# Disable D3plus width change animation

Tags: javascript, animation, width, d3plus

I have to change dynamically the width of a D3plus chart, the problem is that the change in width is not instantaneous but there is an animation that scales the chart down or up accordingly, is there any way to disable this animation or all the eventual animation in general in D3plus?

This is the code i use:

```
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
            .container('#' + id)
            .data(data)
            .type('tree_map')
            .id('name')
            .size('value')
            .width($(window).width() - 85)
            .draw();

    $(window).on('orientationchange', function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
                visualization.width($(window).width() - 85).draw();
        }, 200);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Transitions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) ?
Can't test without showing how are you changing the `width` atribute but if you set `.transition(0)` then it will update whatever you are changing (width or any style) instantly.

With this JSFiddle if you change the value of .duration(3000) to .duration(0) [line 46] the animation dissapears.

With animation:
http://jsfiddle.net/k5rw9qr5/

With `.duration(0)`:
http://jsfiddle.net/pha367zu/1/

Comment: I've updated the question with my code. I tried your solution but i couldn't manage to make it work (I haven't used d3 directly till now so i'm not sure if I used it correctly), do you have any suggestion based on my code?

Answer (score -1):

The [D3plus documentation](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#timing) lists a .timing() method that can be modified. You would probably want to set the transition timing to zero:

```
visualization.timing({"transitions": 0})
```